CloudFront: The certificate attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add
I have been working on resolving an issue for the past two days and need help. I had my hosting and domain on GoDaddy and decided to move only the hosting to AWS. I successfully moved the hosting to AWS using AWS S3 and Route 53.
After the migration, I realized the website was not secure, so I decided to add SSL to it. I used Certificate Manager to create a certificate for example.com, www.example.com and *.example.com, and added their records on Route 53.
Then, I created a CloudFront distribution for example.com and was able to access the website using https. However, when I tried to access the website using https://www.example.com, it didn't work. I attempted to add another distribution in CloudFront, but when I added www.example.com in CNAME, I received this error:

The certificate attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add.

The certificate includes www.example.com and is issued. Please help me resolve this issue.
When someone enters https://www. at the beginning of the URL, they can't access it, and the website is only accessible if I type example.com or https://example.com.
Here is the error in the cloudfront while creating the distribution:

